# Problem using NSString compare:options:range, conflicting results

Tags: iphone, comparison, nsstring

Ohh, what is wrong with this code !?!?!

```
    NSString *s1 = @"5 Oct 2010 18:30";
    NSString *s2 = @"5 Oct 2010 09:47";
    NSRange range = {0, 11}; // Both "D MMM YYYY " and "DD MMM YYYY"
    NSComparisonResult result = 0;
    result = [s1 compare:s2 options:NSLiteralSearch range:range];
    // result == -1
    NSString *sa = [s1 substringWithRange:range];
    NSString *sb = [s2 substringWithRange:range];
    result = [sa compare:sb];
    // result == 0
```

Why do I get different results from those two comperes? As far as I can tell, they should be same?

Comment: want to get even more confused? Try: result = [s1 compare:s1 options:NSLiteralSearch range:range];

Comment: That's -1 !!! Is compare totally broken ???

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's a better answer, thanks to the kind people at the CocoaDev mailing list!

The 'range' referred to in the method signature is the range **of the receiving string** only.

So, in your first example, you are comparing the characters in range of s1 with the whole of s2; and that, correctly, is reported as -1.

This explains the apparent anomaly noted by fluchtpunkt, as well.

Comment: Heh, many thanx for solution! Now I just need to figure out how such a disabled compare could be used. Not going to be easy...

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing wrong with it; sa and sb have the same values, but s1 and s2 do not.

EDIT:

Sorry, read it too quickly. There is indeed a problem - see below.

Comment: I use range in first comparison, isn't it supposed to be taken into account? Why else is it there?

Comment: I think the compiler makes sa and sb the same object - so that would explain why you get 0 in that case. But I still can't see why the first version doesn't work! I've experimented with a few variations, and I'm now confused...

Comment: I give up! I've posted a recipe to Apple's CocoaDev mailing list, and will let you know what response I get.